# Limit of a sum where each term is a function of the summation limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that the following limit is finite:

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{2^i-1}{2^k-2^i}$$

Actually, it would be nice to prove that

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{2^i-1}{2^k-2^i} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i-1} = E \approx 1.6067$$

ie the Erdös-Borwein constant. Standard tests doesn't work and WolframAlpha freezes when I tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^k-2^i}=0$$

Then use that $\frac{2^i}{2^k-2^i}=\frac{1}{2^{k-i}-1}$.

Comment: I deleted my answer so as not to infringe on your hint. Sorry about that ;-)

Comment: No reason to apologize - you clearly took more than a few minutes to write your answer, and my answer arrived only two minutes ahead of your. No reason to delete yours, unless you think it is just too explicit. @DavidZ

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure of the community norms on how to respond to questions like this, but on reflection I do think it's better to give hints than full solutions. So I'll leave mine deleted.

Comment: Yeah this is perfect.